# How To Accept Different Currencies Using Postgresql Money Type Variable In Yii?

Tags: php, yii, internationalization

In my Yii web application, PostgreSQL Money type variable only support value with $,  i.e. $100.

How can I accept value with different currency format. i.e., £100 or €100 ?

Comment: Maybe http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CNumberFormatter#formatCurrency-detail

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. If I use this then I think I need to setup currency format manually. I would like to use this dynamically.

Comment: is it related to Yii or postgres?

Comment: Yii @Ali MasudianPour